# R mailr package not loading Java

Tags: java, r, rjava, ubuntu-20.04

I am working in an Ubuntu 20.04 machine trying to run an R script that sends a pdf with `mail`R package. I have installed Oracle Java and run "`sudo R CMD javareconf`". This is the output

```
  meteo@BOIRA:~/PROJECTES/SANITAT/TREBALL$ sudo R CMD javareconf
*** JAVA_HOME is not a valid path, ignoring
Java interpreter : /usr/bin/java
Java version     : 14.0.1
Java home path   : /usr/lib/jvm/java-14-oracle
Java compiler    : /usr/bin/javac
Java headers gen.:
Java archive tool: /usr/bin/jar

trying to compile and link a JNI program
detected JNI cpp flags    : -I$(JAVA_HOME)/include -I$(JAVA_HOME)/include/linux
detected JNI linker flags : -L$(JAVA_HOME)/lib/server -ljvm
gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-14-oracle/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-14-oracle/include/linux    -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-V28x5H/r-base-3.6.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c conftest.c -o conftest.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o conftest.so conftest.o -L/usr/lib/jvm/java-14-oracle/lib/server -ljvm -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR


JAVA_HOME        : /usr/lib/jvm/java-14-oracle
Java library path: $(JAVA_HOME)/lib/server
JNI cpp flags    : -I$(JAVA_HOME)/include -I$(JAVA_HOME)/include/linux
JNI linker flags : -L$(JAVA_HOME)/lib/server -ljvm
Updating Java configuration in /usr/lib/R
Done.
```

Then I have installed `rJava`, apparently successfull. But when I try to load `mailr` package I get this error:

```
library(rJava)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/home/meteo/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/rJava/libs/rJava.so':
  libjvm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

But `rJava.so` exists in */home/meteo/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/rJava/libs/*

If I `echo $JAVA_HOME` it is empty. I think R does not properly find java but can't figure out how to point R to actual java installation, assuming Java is installed

```
meteo@BOIRA:~/PROJECTES/SANITAT/TREBALL$ java -version
java version "14.0.1" 2020-04-14
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 14.0.1+7)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.0.1+7, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Try putting `$(JAVA_HOME)/lib/server` on `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` - `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/lib/server:${PATH}`

Comment: I just tried but it didn't work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally found the answer googleing, hope it helps someone in the future

I needed to copy `javax.activation-api-1.2.0.jar` and `javax.activation-1.2.0.jar` in the mailR java directory in my server `/home/meteo/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/mailR/java`

Now it is working fine.

Comment: Good to know! Sounds like a crazy dependency issue :)

Comment: From where should i copy those files?